# How to decode an XMPP message in Erlang with ejabberd?

Tags: erlang, decode, encode, ejabberd

I am using ejabberd 14.07.

When I send a space character in a message, it is replaced by the "+" symbol.
What do I need to do to decode the message, for example message = "Hi test" means it will receive "Hi+test".

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to ejabberd. ejabberd XMPP client (c2s) or server (s2s) connection does not replace space with + symbol. It looks like you have a web tool injecting content into ejabberd and that it does not decode its input properly.